# Cannot connect to Database Engine

Tags: sql-server

I started an SQL Server instance(it is in running state), now I would like to connect to it in `MS SQL Server Management Studio`. I got following error.

```
TITLE: Connect to Database Engine
------------------------------

Cannot connect to KOVACSA.

Login failed for user 'myemail@outlook.hu'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)
```

I am using `SQL Server authentication method`, because I choosed `Log on as This user` option.

Comment: "I am using SQL Server authentication method." Did you configure this both on client _and_ server? Can you log in as `sa`? If so, can you verify `myemail@outlook.hu` appears in the list of logins?

Comment: I have configured it in Configuration Manager and Management Studio. I cannot login with `sa` instead of my login.

Comment: I can't see anything in Object Explorer, because I cannot connect, so I cannot see exsting users.

Comment: Is there _any_ way you can still log in to the SQL Server instance (SQL Server Auth or Windows Auth)?

Comment: While installing SQL Server, you are supposed to specify a password for `sa`. Forget the password and you may find yourself locked out. In my own painful experience, fastest solution is to uninstall and re-install SQL Server.

Comment: It throws several error messages always. This tool isn't suitable so for everyday use.